# What is the intuitive way of proving that a function is total?

Tags: functions, discrete-mathematics, elementary-set-theory

I am experiencing a huge disconnect from learning theory behind set theory and actually applying them.

For a function to be total, we know it must satisfy these two properties, given some function $F: A \to B$:

1. Function property (i.e. common for both partial and total function): $$\forall a\in A .\forall b, b' \in B. aFb \ \land aFb' \implies b = b' $$
2. Total property:

$$\forall a \in A, \exists b\in B . aFb$$

To give you my thoughts on this:

1. Function property means that for all inputs from A, if it **ever** results in an output, there can only be one output from an input. This makes sense since we want our function to produce only one answer, not multiple ones.
2. Total property means that we ensure all inputs from A **will** get an output, and so the "total" or inclusive idea of this property.

But how do I actually apply these concepts in problems? To elucidate my problem, here is an example:

#### Question

Show that $F: A \to B$ is a function if and only if there exists a relation $G : B \to A$ such that $id_A \subseteq G \circ F$ and $F\circ G \subseteq id_B$.

#### Attempt

We have two things to prove:

1. There exists $G: B \to A \implies id_A \subseteq G \circ F \land F\circ G \subseteq id_B$.
2. $ id_A \subseteq G \circ F \land F\circ G \subseteq id_B \implies G: B \to A$

To prove the first part:

$$b (F \circ G) b' \implies \forall b,b' \in B. \exists a \in A. bGa \land aFb'$$
$$\implies \forall b, b' \in B. G(b) = a \land F(a) = b'$$
$$\implies b'= b$$

Methodology:
I try to present the way of thinking of how I solve it.

1. I first choose some arbitrary $b$ and $b'$ from the set $B$ composition of $F \circ G$.
2. I expand to represent in terms of $aFb$ etc.
3. Then I convert it into a function form (e.g. $F(a) = B$)
4. Finally, I extract the insight from this: i.e. $b = b'$ This means the composition result in the identity relation and is so a subset of it.

Is this a common technique to use and solve? Moreover, the last line seems a bit coerced. What is it in my reasoning that forces it to be equal? $G$ can be a function that maps to some $a$ that will not give $b'=b$. I have no intuitive understanding of this line of reasoning except that it fulfils the question criteria.

How do I then organize my argument in terms of arguing for the total property and function property in two ways? It seems like I have 4 things to argue here, and I'm lost.

Comment: so total just mean bijective??????????

Comment: This is off-topic, but where are you getting this "$G:B\mapsto A$" notation, e.g. what book?

Comment: In the first part, you have to prove that if there is such a $G$ then $F$ is a function.  You haven't addressed this at all.  You are saying if $b(F\circ G)b'$ then $b=b'$.  Yes indeed, that's what it means to say $F\circ G \subset id_B$   You are just restating part of the hypothesis, so far as I can see.

Comment: @saulspatz It is true that I did not explicitly state whether there is such a G, but I think the reasoning is trying to see whether there is such a "G" at all, by trying if it satisfy the condition. If it satisfies, such a G can exist, otherwise it cannot..is there another way I can prove this?

Comment: @DerekElkins I'm not too sure if I can recall the book I got the notation from, but I'm learning from pretty archaic notes (decades ago) obtained from a friend who studied the course a long time ago.

Comment: As you say, you are having trouble applying the theory to solve the problems.  I have to say that I think it's because you are getting tangled up in the notation, writing stuff without really considering what it means.  This is a very common problem, and I think it is a real mistake to try to write these symbol-ridden proofs when you are just starting out.  It's much better to try to write the proofs in English.

Comment: @saulspatz One thing I'm worried is the lack of formalism in presenting proofs. Would you be able to show a short proof that leads to proof of the solution? I've considered what I've wrote as far as I could, just that the last line is the best try I could give in an attempt to prove, unfortunately.

Comment: It doesn't look true to me.  It seems to be saying that $F$ has a two-sided inverse, namely that $F$ is bijective.  I'll look at it some more.  "Formalism" is not so important at this stage.  See https://terrytao.wordpress.com/career-advice/theres-more-to-mathematics-than-rigour-and-proofs/ by one of the most famous mathematicians in the world.

Comment: Weird notation. Here's how I look at it. $f$ is a (total) function mapping the elements of set $A$ to the elements of set $B$ iff $\forall x\in A: f(x)\in B$. And what does $id_a$ mean?

Comment: I would guess that the most common way to prove that a function is total is simply that the composition of total functions is also total.

Comment: From the question, I suppose the question is trying to say $G$ is the inverse function of $F$. Working with this assumption, does it make the question solvable? For $id_a$, it means the identity relation: $ \forall a \in A. aFa$ for example

Comment: Surely it is $id_A$ and $id_B$?